# Dynamic SQL to get rows from information_schema

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql, information-schema

Let’s say I’m looking for a specific column in my database so I have something like this

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like ‘%employeeid%’
```

But I also want to know how many rows each table has, I was told I can do this using Dynamic SQL so I have this now

```
DECLARE 
    @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colName NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE CUR_TABLE CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

OPEN CUR_TABLE
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TABLE
INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    
    SET @colName = '%employeeid%'
    SET @sql = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tableName +') AS ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where column_name like ' + ''' + @colName + ''';
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TABLE
    INTO @tableName

END;

CLOSE CUR_TABLE
DEALLOCATE CUR_TABLE



EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But this doesn't work, What I'm trying to do is query a table with the column I am looking for, with the table name, and number of rows in the table.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you be a little more vague than "this doesn't work"? Does executing the dynamic SQL statement _inside_ the loop help? Do you not care about which schema the table is in? Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: As to why the original SQL didn't work, I could see a couple of issues. The @sql was set multiple times inside the loop, but only the last value was executed at the end. Your column name condition should likely be moved from the dynamic SQL out to the select the feeds the cursor. The dynamic SQL would no longer reference  INFORMATION_SCHEMA  The COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME values would then need to be substituted into the dynamic SQL. On a side note, when substituting object names or string values into dynamic sql, good practice is to use QUOTENAME() to protect against weird or dangerous names.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SQL Server's dynamic management views to quickly obtain the row counts*.

Find all tables with a column named 'MyColumn' and their current rows:

```
select Schema_Name(t.schema_id) schemaName, t.name TableName, s.row_count
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
join sys.dm_db_partition_stats s on s.object_id = c.object_id and s.index_id <= 1
where c.name='MyColumn';
```

* *Accurate except for frequently updated tables where there could be some lag*

Answer (score 1):

The following uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA, dynamic SQL, and STRING_AGG() to build a query that will return a single result set.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname = 'ProductID'

DECLARE @Newline VARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @SqlTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    + 'SELECT'
    + ' ColumnName = <ColumnNameString>,'
    + ' TableName = <TableSchemaAndNameString>,'
    + ' Rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TableSchemaAndName>)'
    + @Newline
DECLARE @UnionSql NVARCHAR(100) = 'UNION ALL ' + @Newline

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            @SqlTemplate
            , '<ColumnNameString>', QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME, ''''))
            , '<TableSchemaAndNameString>', QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME, ''''))
            , '<TableSchemaAndName>', QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME))
        , @UnionSql)
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        ON C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' -- Omit views
    AND C.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
)

SET @Sql = @Sql + 'ORDER BY Rows DESC, TableName' + @Newline

--PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

I generalized it a bit by adding TABLE_SCHEMA so that it could be used with the AdventureWorks database. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=17f76f21f4a734366753f6f67633e1c7) for a working demo. Also included is equivalent logic that uses FOR XML instead of STRING_AGG for older SQL Server versions.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, here is a shorthand way using `sp_msforeachtable`.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(200) = 'ContactID'

CREATE TABLE #T
(
    ColumnName NVARCHAR(200), 
    TableName NVARCHAR(200), 
    RecordCount INT
)

INSERT INTO #T (ColumnName, TableName)
SELECT 
    ColumnName = C.COLUMN_NAME, 
    TableName = '['+C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+C.TABLE_NAME+']' 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE 
    C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%' + @ColumnName + '%'

EXEC SP_MSFOREACHTABLE 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #T WHERE TableName = ''?'') UPDATE #T SET RecordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ? ) WHERE TableName = ''?'''

SELECT 
    ColumnName,TableName,
    TableType = CASE 
                    WHEN RecordCount IS NULL 
                        THEN 'View' 
                        ELSE 'Table' 
                END,
    RecordCount
FROM 
    #T
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN RecordCount IS NULL THEN 'View' ELSE 'Table' END

DROP TABLE #T
```